# Como percorrer uma lista enumerável e checar se a propriedade se repete na lista durante as voltas do foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tenho uma lista (`IEnumerable`) chamada Pessoas que contém as propriedades Id, DataNasc, etc... Preciso trazer esses dados para uma `listview` no `html` usando o `Razor` (ou pode ser fora da página cshtml, nos arquivos .cs).

Digamos que a pessoa 1 tem

> Id 1, DataNasc 23/03/2000;

E a pessoa 2 (exibida na segunda volta do foreach na view) tem:

> Id 2, e DataNasc 23/03/2000;

**Sendo a DataNasc igual na pessoa 1 e 2...**

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta do tipo:
"se o valor da propriedade DataNasc, na lista Pessoas é igual para várias pessoas, retorne todas essas pessoas que nasceram nesse mesmo dia".

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Estou usando C# Asp.Net MVC 4 com Razor View.

Sou novo no C#, estava tentando fazer isso, que parando pra pensar acho que não faz muito sentido, mas estou colocando para talvez tentar ilustrar o que queria, embora com a lógica errada.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Pessoas)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pessoas.Count(); i++)
    {
        var arr = Model.Pessoas.ToArray();
        if (item.DataNasc == arr[i].DataNasc)
        {
            <p>@arr[i].DataNasc</p>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: se você tiver uma lista com estas 5 datas: 23/03/2000; 23/03/2000; 30/01/2002; 10/02/2001;10/02/2001... qual seria o output pretendido?

Comment: Tu queres fazer um agrupamento?

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, já pensou em usar um dicionario `Dictionary<>`? Como chave pode utilizar um `DateTime` e como valor uma lista da classe pessoas `List<Pessoa>`.

Exemplo:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Pessoa>> comMesmaData;
// Para checar se já há pessoas com esta data ou inserir novas!!!
if (comMesmaData.Conteins(DATA))
    comMesmaData[DATA].Add(NOVA_PESSOA);
else
    comMesmaData.Add(DATA, NOVA_PESSOA);
```

Ao final você terá todos os dados das pessoas agrupadas por data.

Comment: olá! obrigado pela resposta! estou usando uma lista enumerable, pelo que entendi não rola com ela

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem o que pretende com isso, mas você mesmo já percebeu isso conforme colocou na sua pergunta. Digo isso por que você pode ter *N* grupos que se repetem. Por exemplo:

> Id 1, DataNasc 23/03/2000;
>
> Id 1, DataNasc 11/07/1990;
>
> Id 1, DataNasc 23/03/2000;
>
> Id 1, DataNasc 11/07/1990;
>
> Id 1, DataNasc 23/03/2000;
>
> Id 1, DataNasc 01/01/1989;

Aqui você tem um grupo de três pessoas que nasceram em **23/03/2000** e outro grupo com duas pessoas que nasceram em **11/07/1990**. Qual das duas repetições você listaria?

**Veja algumas formas de trabalhar os valores repetidos que encontrar nas explicações abaixo.**

---

### Verificando se há valores repetidos em uma lista

Tenho um método que costumo usar para verificar itens repetidos em uma lista de `string`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> VerificarItensRepetidos(IEnumerable<string> listString)
{
    List<string> duplicateKeys = new List<string>();
    List<string> notDuplicateKeys = new List<string>();
    foreach (var text in listString)
    {
        if (notDuplicateKeys.Contains(text))
        {
            duplicateKeys.Add(text);
        }
        else
        {
            notDuplicateKeys.Add(text);
        }
    }
    return duplicateKeys;
}
```

No seu caso você quer verificar uma **Data**, então fiz uma melhoria no método 
 na explicação abaixo para ele comparar qualquer tipo.

---

### Comparando qualquer tipo

Com o exemplo abaixo qualquer tipo pode ser verificado, ao invés de apenas `string` como no meu exemplo anterior:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> VerificarItensRepetidos<T>(IEnumerable<T> listString)
{
    List<object> duplicateKeys = new List<object>();
    List<object> notDuplicateKeys = new List<object>();
    foreach (var text in listString)
    {
        if (notDuplicateKeys.Contains(text))
        {
            duplicateKeys.Add(text);
        }
        else
        {
            notDuplicateKeys.Add(text);
        }
    }
    return duplicateKeys.Cast<T>();
}
```

O método retorna a lista com os itens repetidos. Veja um exemplo de uso:

```
var listaRespetidos = Helper.VerificarItensRepetidos(minhaListaString);
if(listaRespetidos.Count() > 0)
{
    //faça aqui as tratativas necessárias...
}
```

Como você quer trabalhar os itens que tenham a mesma data de nascimento, talvez no seu caso percorrer cada item retornado (`foreach`) e realizar uma busca na sua lista para cada um desses grupos separadamente.

---

**Veja um exemplo no Dot Net fiddle aplicado ao seu problema utilizando o método acima:**


### Dot Net fiddle